# make query string based on input selector

Tags: jquery, input, attributes, selector, datalist

on a user input form, i have some input. some of them bind to datalist and datalist has id & value like this:

```
<input list="browserList" id="browser" value="opera"/>
<datalist id="browserList">
<option id="1" value="Chrome">
<option id="2" value="Firefox">
<option id="3" value="Opera">
<option id="4" value="Safari">
</datalist>

<input list="colorList" id="color" value="blue"/>
<datalist id="colorList">
<option id="0" value="red"/>
<option id="1" value="blue"/>
<option id="2" value="green"/>
</datalist>

<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="text" id="family"/>
```

now i try to make a query string on input text value & datalist id. so i write 2 jquery function : first fetch id from datalist

```
function sysGetDLID(dataListID,inputID)
{ return     $('#'+dataListID).find('option[value="'+$('#'+inputID).val()+'"]').attr('id'); }
```

and next :

```
function inputSelector2QueryString(whatSelector)
 { var queryString = '';
   $(whatSelector).each(function() 
    { var elem=$(this); 
      queryString = queryString 
                  + '&' 
                  + elem.id 
                  + '=' 
                  + (elem.attr('list')!=='' 
                    ? sysGetDLID(elem.id+'List',elem.val())
                    : elem.val()); });
 return queryString; }
```

but when i call inputSelector2QueryString to make query string nothing return. why?

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this yourself instead of using jQuery's `.serialize()` function?

Comment: And if you're going to be using this in an AJAX call, jQuery allows you to specify the data as an object, and it will convert it to a query string for you.

Comment: i have no idea about .serialize(), but i solve it with some of change in my code, based on @Edgar Villegas Alvarado notification. tnx Edgar. this is my code, maybe useful for others : `$(whatSelector).each(function() { queryString = queryString + '&' + this.id + '=' + (typeof $(this).attr('list') == 'undefined' ? $(this).val() : sysGetDLID(this.id+'List',this.id)); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
elem.id
```

you have to do

```
elem.attr("id")
```

(or `this.id`, too)

because `elem` is a jQuery object.

In your code, `elem.id` was `undefined`, so concatenating to the other strings also resulted in an unwanted value

Cheers

Comment: You could also use `this.id`, since `elem` is just a jQuery wrapper around `this`.

Comment: Yep, that's another option

Comment: _"so concatenating to the other strings also resulted in undefined"_ Actually no, in string concatenation `undefined` value becomes a string `undefinedAstring`.